# Extend Copy area if specific word is present

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I wrote a code in which I filter specific things and paste them somewhere else.

How can I extend the copy area by one line, only if there is a specific word?
If possible, I would like to write the content of the column that has now been copied into a cell in which a value already exists.

Here is the Code I already have:

```
Sub Filtern()

Dim Lrow As Long
Dim lngLetzte As Long


With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Datenbasis")
        If .AutoFilterMode = False Then .Range("B:M").AutoFilter
        lngLetzte = .AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
        'Filter wählen Kategorien"
        
.Range("A:M").AutoFilter 8, "X"
.Range("A:M").AutoFilter 2, "Y"
.Range("A:M").AutoFilter 9, "Z"


 If .Columns(3).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
        
            .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(lngLetzte, 14)).Copy
            With Worksheets("L")
            
                Lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                .Range("D" & Lrow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End With
End If
```

[Database Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCQYk.png)
[Outcome Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHhBB.png)

Comment: Do you speak in the question about "How can I extend the copy area by one line" and your code tries copying from the second row to the last one. Do you want copying the next row **from the filtered range**, or all **filtered range up to the last filtered row**, or **all existing rows** (not only the visible ones) from the second one to the last filtered one?

Comment: I want to Copy all existing rows. 
Let's see if i can make it a little bit easier to Understand. 
I Have things which i Copy Always in Rows A:M 
But If in Row N stands the Word "Example" I want to copy A:N. 

The reason why I don't always want to copy A:N is because there is also a lot of  unnecessary input in this row.

Comment: So, the fact that the sheet is filtered does  not matter at all? If so, what's wrong with your code? I must confess that now I am more confused than without asking for clarifications... Please, edit your question and place two pictures (if not something editable). In the first one the range as it exists and in the second one with what you want copying. Or marked somehow on the first picture the range to be copied, according to what logic...

Comment: Should we understand that your actual code does its job, meaning that it copies **everything** from the second row to the last one, column 3 to 14 and you only want adapting it to copy rows **only in some specific circumstances**? For example, in case of a specific word on a specific column? What  "How can I extend the copy area by one line" should mean?

Comment: Yes, thats what i mean.  I Want to adapt it. So it always copys row 3 to 14. But copys row 1-15 if row 15 includes a specific word.

Comment: Can you explain what "How can I extend the copy area by one line" should mean? So, the filtering part does not matter, what matters is (**only**) one word to be found in column "N:N". When it is found the range to be copied should be "C2:M" & the row keeping the key ward. Is this understanding correct? I am asking it because you did not ask anything in your question regarding this aspect... Or there are more such a word occurrences and you need to copy only the rows having it on column "N:N"?

Comment: Hi FaneDuru, i added some Pictures.. Sorry I'm not a native speaker maybe i did not express myself in the wright wray. I Hope you can now understand what I mean? The Input is just random.. It's just to show you what I'm trying to do..